# Angular on top of ASP.NET MVC, displaying Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

We are putting an angular front end on an existing  asp.net c# MVC applicaiton.  In our server code, we extensilvely use custom exceptions to return buisness rule errors.

Is there a best practice or slickest way to handle an exception on an mvc controller or an webApi controller (actually bullbing up from the buisness layer) and getting it across to angular and displaying it in a "user error" popup? How are folks solving this problem?

Comment: Since this isn't code specific it might be better in the Programmers Stack Exchange

Comment: Our alternative to yellow screen of death is javascript alert with sorry message. It's exception and should not happen, so we think it's okay. But standard errors are handled according to situation.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, how are these handled on the Angualr side?

Comment: yellow screen of death is just for you, eg dont change the settings to allow general users see them, use something like elmah as it will LOG MOST of NOT ALL of your errors. Then with a tiny bit of JS you can manage them the angular way for ajax type calls.

Comment: @ChargerllC - While the question didn't contain code, I was looking for (and got) code in the answers, does that make it Kosher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other guys already gave great answers, but I want to elaborate my approach since I guess it will be covering both ends (frontend and server) with more details.

Here's my complete approach to error and exception handling in WebAPI + AngularJS applications.

## Step 1. WebApi controllers in Server side

I have a specific DTO for communicating *Validation Errors* to the client, since I believe they are different from `Exception`s. An exception will result in a 500 error, where a validation result should result in 400 (Bad Request) error.

So, here's my `ApiValidationResult` class:

```
public class ApiValidationResult
{
    public List<ApiValidationError> Errors { get; set; }

    public static ApiValidationResult Failure(string errorKey)
    {
        return new ApiValidationResult {Errors = new List<ApiValidationError> {new ApiValidationError(errorKey)}};
    }

    // You can add a bunch of utility methods here
}

public class ApiValidationError
{
    public ApiValidationError()
    {
    }

    public ApiValidationError(string errorKey)
    {
        ErrorKey = errorKey;
    }

    // More utility constructors here

    public string PropertyPath { get; set; }
    public string ErrorKey { get; set; }
    public List<string> ErrorParameters { get; set; }
}
```

I always use my own base class for WebApi (and MVC) controllers, so I can use them to add handy result method, such as this:

```
public abstract class ExtendedApiController : ApiController
{
    protected IHttpActionResult ValidationError(string error)
    {
        return new ValidationErrorResult(ApiValidationResult.Failure(error), this);
    }

    // More utility methods can go here
}
```

It uses a custom `IHttpActionResult` that I've created specifically for this purpose:

```
public class ValidationErrorResult : NegotiatedContentResult<ApiValidationResult>
{
    public ValidationErrorResult(ApiValidationResult content, IContentNegotiator contentNegotiator, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters) 
        : base(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, content, contentNegotiator, request, formatters)
    {
    }

    public ValidationErrorResult(ApiValidationResult content, ApiController controller)
        : base(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, content, controller)
    {
    }
}
```

As a result, I can cleanly use codes such as this in my controller actions:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SomeAction(SomeInput input)
    {
        // Do whatever...
        if (resultIsValid)
        {
            return Ok(outputObject);
        }

        return ValidationResult(errorMessage);
    }
```

## Step 2. Handling unexpected exceptions

As I said, I believe that only real unhandled `Exception`s should result in a 500 (Internal server error) responses.

Such unhandled exceptions are automatically converted to a 500 result by WebApi. The only thing I need to do about them, is to log them. So, I create an implementation of `IExceptionLogger` interface and register it like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new UnhandledExceptionLogger());
```

## Step 3. Intercepting and showing errors in Client side

AngularJS allows intercepting all HTTP calls sent from `$http` service. I use this to centralize all message popups. Here's my interceptor code:

```
appModule.factory("errorsHttpInterceptor", [
    "$q", "$rootScope", "$injector",
    ($q: ng.IQService, $rootScope: IAppRootScopeService, $injector) => {
        return {
            'responseError': rejection => {
                // Maybe put the error in $rootScope and show it in UI
                // Maybe use a popup
                // Maybe use a 'toast'
                var toastr = $injector.get('toastr');
                toastr.error(...);

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

You can do all sorts of things in the interceptor, such as logging debug messages, or applying key to display-string translation of error codes. You can also distinguish between 500 and 400 errors, and display different types of error messages.

I use **toastr** library which I think shows a nice UI and is very handy in API level.

Finally, I register the interceptor like this:

```
appModule.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    ($httpProvider: ng.IHttpProvider) => {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorsHttpInterceptor');
    }
]);
```

The syntax is in TypeScript, which is very similar to JavaScript and I'm sure you can figure out what it means.

Comment: Awesome Detailed answer! Thanks, I'm not marking an answer till i implement it and see which works best,(which may be a bit) but i upvoted it for the great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Typically, I Have been doing this kind of thing within our WEB API, returning the correct status code is key with this, this is of course completely agnostic as to which of the many front end frameworks you want to use.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(DateTime? updatesAfter = null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do something here.
                return this.Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // Be more specific if you like...
            {
                return this.InternalServerError(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The helper methods that are now shipped with Web Api v2 ApiControllers are excellent...

```
this.BadRequest()
this.InternalServerError()
this.Ok()
this.Unauthorized()
this.StatusCode()
this.NotFound()
```

Some of them (such as InternalServerError) allow you to pass an exception or message (or simply an object) as a param.

Typically as with any front end framework or library there will be a fail or error callback that you can provide when initialising the ajax call to your API method, this will be called in scenarios where error status codes are returned.

Answer (score 2):

We have just finished a large MVC app with an Angular frontend.

We just let errors flow, eg any webpages just get an error has but without the stack trace (not the yellow screen, the nice Error has *** but within your master page etc)

Web API calls just return the correct HTTP status. They can include some details if you wish.

But, you dont want to lose these errors, so we just installed elmah with

```
Install-Package elmah
```

and, it JUST WORKS, errors just end up in the log, users get told something as not worked etc.. NO extra work needed

To make our UI nicer we did the following, for

**Unhandled errors**

*MVC Pages*

Just let MVC front end do its job, it will tell the user in a nice way something has gone wrong.

*Angular web calls*

in the .error function alert the user eg

```
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.addAlert('danger', 'Error deleting autosave details');
}
```

Let errors stack, if you don't to lose an error due to an error overwriting it. addAlert just writes to an array that is data bound to on the front end.

**Handled Errors**
If you are handling them, then you have managed what happens, but to log these

*MVC*

If you wish to just log them, the `elmah` API has a single call for this

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception );
```

If you are using error attributes then you can use this

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}

public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
        if (context.ExceptionHandled)
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
    }
}
```

Also, for general logging to the ELMAH framework checkout https://github.com/TrueNorthIT/Elmah

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is returning Content.

Here is how I do it (end-to-end). From my API:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.<statuscode>, "ResponseContent: " + "my_custom_error");
```

Here, HttpStatusCode. and "my_custom_error" can be the response returned from another API Layer. In that case, I simply read the response from that layer and pass it to the client side.

```
//If I'm getting output from another API/Layer then I pass it's output like this
var output = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
return Content(response.StatusCode, "ResponseContent: " + output);
```

For more details on HttpStatusCodes, please refer [HttpStatusCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx)

And in the Angular code, I read it like this:

```
$http({ method: methodType, url: endpoint })
     .then(function (response) {
          response.status; //gets you the HttpStatusCode to play with
          response.data; //gets you the ReponseContent section
     }, function (response) {
          response.status; //gets you the HttpStatusCode
          response.data; //gets you the ReponseContent section
     });
```

*Make sure while making http calls the `responseType` is not set to 'JSON'. Since the data returned by the API is not in JSON format at this stage.*

From [$http service in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), the response object has these properties:

> data    – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the
>   transform functions.
>
> status  – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
>
> headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>
> config  – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to
>   generate the request.
>
> statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

Answer (score 0):

For my API Controllers I return `HttpResponseMessage`. Please see my example below. I hope this helps.

On the response message you can also pass back your object to the front end.

**WEB API**

```
    // Get all
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myObject);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error Message");
        }
    }
```

**Angular JS**

```
// Get Request on Page Load
    $http({
        url: '/api/department/',
        method: 'GET',
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.departments = data;
    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.error = error;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger animate-show" role="alert" ng-show="error != null">{{ error }} </div>
<div class="alert alert-success animate-show" role="alert" ng-show="success != null">{{ success }}</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the many edits, all should be there now for what you need :)